# Make a custom launch page in my IOS application with fade out image

Tags: swift, animation, fade

So I am making a custom launch first page for my app. I am navigating to the next screen with a Timer. However my question is about my first page. When I launch the app I want the image that I am using to appear right away. I am not even sure if this is an option. because all apps that I see, when I launch it takes some time to load. I was wondering if this is the reason there is a delay for the image to appear or I can do something to make it appear instantly? I have attached my code below:

```
import UIKit

class LaunchViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(runTimedCode), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1")
        self.view.addSubview(imageView)

        imageView.fadeOut()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor,constant:20).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor,constant:30).isActive = true
        imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor,constant:10).isActive = true
        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor,constant:10).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func runTimedCode()
    {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromLaunch", sender: self)
    }
}
extension UIView {

    func fadeIn(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func fadeOut(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 1.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try moving your code from `viewDidAppear` to `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Note however that there is *always* a delay between the user tapping on your app's icon and the appearance of your first screen. That is why you have a LaunchScreen.storyboard - it is what is shown during that delay. So maybe you should put your image in the LaunchScreen.storyboard. Note that you cannot run any *code* in conjunction with the LaunchScreen.storyboard.

Comment: Ok i had to leave my computer. I will check back in few hours and let you know. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: so I moved the code to what you suggested and I still see a blank page when the app loads before my image shows up :(

Comment: Then you're not sharing enough information. Try to reproduce this problem starting from a totally blank Single View App project template and, if you can do so, describe to us how to see the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to move your code to *viewDidLoad*.
*viewDidLoad* is called only once during `UIViewController` lifecycle.
While viewDidAppear might be called several times.

Since you are using Autolayout you don't need to care about correct subviews size and moving your code to *viewDidLoad* should be sufficient and it should resolve issue with delay you have asked about.

Comment: Ok I will try your method later today and let you know. I remember i did try the didload and did not work the way I wanted though. I ll give it another shot

Comment: you need to add imageView in viewDidLoad.
However you need to start timer on viewDidAppear. I think starting timer and adding imageView in different methods of UIViewController is a reason of inconsistent behavior.
You are starting timer before adding imageView now.